# How can I display the values in HTML for unknown properties in a object?

Tags: html, angular, object, ngfor

I have an array(formResponses) of objects. My object structure is as shown below. In the below picture I have userResponses object, where I have keys and value loaded dynamically. I want to display userResponses object in my HTML. How can I do this?
All the keys and values in userResponses object are loaded differently each time.

[image]

I know I can display if I do it  like this:

```
<p>{{userResponses.firstName}}</p>
<p>{{userResponses.lastName}}</p>
```

But, I don't know what values are loaded everytime. Is there a way to display any value which is in the object.

```html
<table>
        <thead>
            <th>Name/Attributes</th>
            <th>arrtibute1</th>
            <th>attribute2</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let item of formResponses">
                <td>{{item.userName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.userResponses.firstName}}</td>
                <td>{{item.userResponses.lastName}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a pipe to loop json keys.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({ name: 'keys' })
export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value): any {
    if(!value) return null;
    return Object.keys(value);
  }
}
```

```
<td *ngFor="let key of item.userResponses | keys">{{item.userResponses[key]}}</td>
```